# SQL QUERY: Not how temp tables are functioning in script I was asked to fix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read over five or six questions here relating to dropping and recreating temp tables. Here's the relevant portion of the script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.staging', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
        
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#SEQ_SERIES', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #SEQ_TEMP

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TEMP_TIME_SERIES', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP_TIME_SERIES

TRUNCATE TABLE staging

INSERT INTO staging(column names)
SELECT (column data) FROM forecast...
```

I understand what's being done with the staging table: we're wiping the existing contents to use it as staging table in the script.

What I don't understand is:

- What does 'U' reference in the staging and temp tables null checks.
- The temp tables are never recreated, yet are used subsequently in the script, *e.g.*

```
    SELECT SEQ_NBR
           , FCST_ID
    INTO #SEQ_SERIES
    FROM data
    WHERE X
        AND Y
        AND Z
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? My understanding is a dropped table cannot be used without being recreated.

To be clear, this script was apparently functioning perfectly until a month or two ago, and this portion of the script hasn't been changed since 2019.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax `SELECT ... INTO table_name` is a way to create a new table. If you are inserting into an existing table you use `INSERT INTO table_name SELECT ...`.
Here is an example.

> ```
> create table data(SEQ_NBR varchar(10),FCST_ID varchar(10));
> insert into data values('dummy','data');
> GO
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
>     SELECT SEQ_NBR
>            , FCST_ID
>     INTO #SEQ_SERIES
>     FROM data;
> GO
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from #SEQ_SERIES;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> SEQ_NBR | FCST_ID
> :------ | :------
> dummy   | data
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dcf13f4d9241d1ed3953b90623bf5975)*